# How do I upgrade to RealTime kernel with a ZFS hardrive?

Tags: upgrade, kernel, realtime

I have enabled the realtime kernel, but when booting I fail to load the ZFS modules. As a result, I drop into a BusyBox shell.

Is there a way to fix this in Ubuntu 22? `

```
22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 10:33:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```